# navigationOptions headerLeft,headerRight and title not working?

Tags: react-native

What I want: put a touchable icon left side that will navigate to my drawer navigator once pressed and the title in the middle then in the right side an icon that has future purposes once clicked

What I tried doing: 
I tried to put the navigationOptions under the MainScreen it still doesn't work.

This is my code in my AppNavigation.js

```
    const primaryNav = createStackNavigator({
    LaunchScreen: { screen: LaunchScreen },
    MainScreen: {
    screen: MainScreen,
    },
    }, {
    // Default config for all screens
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'MainScreen',
    navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: styles.header,
    title: 'TY, Next',
       headerStyle:{
       backgroundColor: "Transparent",
       marginRight: 20,
       marginLeft: 20,
    },
    headerRight: (
       <TouchableOpacity>
        <Icon2 name="sc-telegram" color={Colors.red} size={30} /> 
       </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
    headerLeft: (
        <TouchableOpacity>
        <Icon name="bars" color={Colors.red} size={25}/>
         </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
 }
})
```

Any idea why my code isn't running? There's no title of Ty next not even the 2 icons that I added. I am using igniteCLI for react native.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by using the following codes in my screen.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const {state} = navigation;
    const {} = state;
    return {
        headerStyle:{
            backgroundColor: "Transparent",
            marginRight: 20,
            marginLeft: 20,
        }, 
        headerLeft: (
            <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Icon name="bars" color={Colors.red} size={25}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerLeftStyle: styles.drawerIcon,
        headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Icon2 name="sc-telegram" color={Colors.red} size={30} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerRightStyle: styles.planeIcon,
        headerTransparent:  true,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Icon instead of Icon2
if you are using version with 3x
defaultNavigationOptions 
 instead of navigationOptions

```
headerRight: (
   <TouchableOpacity>
  //-->I changed here  <Icon name="sc-telegram" color={Colors.red} size={30} /> 
   </TouchableOpacity>
),
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution a little bit more.

Comment: i have this as my imports

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import Icon2 from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons'
import Icon3 from 'react-native-vector-icons/Foundation'
import Icon4 from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons'

it wont let me import icon but different icon. I'll try that defaultNavigationOptions and see if it works. :) Thanks for answering!

Comment: hello @sapan  changing to defaultNavigationOptions did not work :/

Comment: @MirkoEbert did you mean me or sapan?

Comment: @Sapan, I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Because that methods are deprecated in 'navigationOptions'.
`headerRight: <SomeElement />` will be removed in a future version.
As like

- `headerRight: () => <SomeElement />`